# TYPO3 - How to pack a new TYPO3 extension as .t3x file

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have updated an already existing extension to support new version of typo3.

Please help me to create corresponding .t3x file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBH I'm not sure if it's possible at all. On the other hand, you don't need to pack extension to t3x as TYPO3 (at least in version 6+) handles .zip files as well in the Extension Manager (**EM**).

Just go to EM, find the ext and click on ***Download as .zip*** icon in Actions column.

So you can install it anywhere by using EM too...

For TYPO3 ver 4.x you can zip extension's folder yourself, and unzip it in other instance and than just use EM to activate it.

If you really want to create t3x still, take a look at the bottom of QA section in [this TYPO3 wiki page](http://wiki.typo3.org/FAQ/T3X_files)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the tool [TYPO3 Extension Utils](https://github.com/etobi/Typo3ExtensionUtils) available, with which you're able to pack an extension as `.t3x`. On Linux this looks like this.

Get the tool.

```
wget http://bit.ly/t3xutils -O t3xutils.phar
```

Make it executable.

```
chmod +x t3xutils.phar
```

Pack the extension.

```
./t3xutils.phar create [ext_key] [path_to_ext] [some_name.t3x]
```

Just replace the placeholders in square brackets with real values. `[path_to_ext]` has to point to the source files (not an archive) of the (modified) extension.